# Azure Redis Cache - Read Through/Write Through

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, distributed-caching, azure-redis-cache

I am building an architecture where we would like to add a caching layer. Caching can have different patterns like cache-aside, read through, write through etc

I wanted to know if we can implement Read Through, Write Through in Azure Redis Managed Instance? I know Azure Redis Cache provides cache aside pattern feature but I would like to implement Read through pattern.

Does the managed instance natively provides read through/write through pattern? If yes, can you please send me the documentation of the implementation steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manages instances don't provide read-through/write-through for that you'll need to use RedisGears module with one of the recipes: [rgsync](https://github.com/RedisGears/rgsync) or [rghibernate](https://github.com/RedisGears/rghibernate)

Comment: Do we need to install Redis on a VM then to integrate rgsync or is it possible to use managed instance and integrate rgSync?

Comment: Currently rgsync is not supported by any of the managed services only by self hosting